# How to hide a row if checkbox is not selected inside html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically created checkboxes inside HTML table like given in the following code. And I am trying to hide the rows whose checkbox is not checked by using below lines of code on the another button click() function.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#allotBtn", function() {
  $('#studentListBody tr [type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, chk) {
    if (!chk.checked) {
      $("#studentList tr:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="studentListBody">
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="centeralign hideFirstTD sorting_1">
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success ">
        <input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox" id="studentId_-5ab87edaff24ae1204000857" name="studentId_-5ab87edaff24ae1204000857" value="5ab87edaff24ae1204000857">
        <label></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="  align-middle ">
      <img alt="image" class="img-circle listProfilePicture" src="../img/studentcap.png">
    </td>
    <td>Raja Mir</td>
    <td>7th</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>Active</td>
    <td>2016</td>
  </tr>

  <tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="centeralign hideFirstTD sorting_1">
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success ">
        <input class="commoncheckbox" type="checkbox" id="studentId_-5ab8d5f8ff24ae120400085f" name="studentId_-5ab8d5f8ff24ae120400085f" value="5ab8d5f8ff24ae120400085f">
        <label></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="  align-middle ">
      <img alt="image" class="img-circle listProfilePicture" src="../img/studentcap.png">
    </td>
    <td>Omer Jan</td>
    <td>4th</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>Active</td>
    <td>2018</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If there are more than 3 rows in the table, the above code hides the rows haphazardly.

Please help!!!

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Can you make a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If you don't show code that demonstrates the failure, this question will probably get closed.

Comment: After generating html table, the user will check the desired checkboxes ftom the table. After that the user will click on the button with id allotBtn. On the click of this button, I need to check if checkbox is checked or not, if checkbox is not checked, then that row should be hidden.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. But you need to provide the code that shows how it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#allotBtn").click(function(){
    $('#studentListBody tr [type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("tr").hide();
});
```

Comment: It seems like he wants a separate "Filter" button, rather than hiding each row as he clicks.

Comment: I have updated my question... This is not what i was trying to achive. please check my question

Comment: Be sure that enclosing the <tbody> by <table> tag.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that `i` in the .each() loop starts indexing the elements at 0, whereas when you call `nth-child` in CSS, the first element is numbered as 1. Therefore the row you hide is always off by 1.

The fix is simple - add 1 to `i` each time you use it to set nth-child:

```
$(document).on("click", "#allotBtn", function () {
    $('#studentListBody tr [type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, chk) {
         if (!chk.checked) {
             $("#studentListBody tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").css("display", "none");
         }
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jqabpru2/9/

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
- https://api.jquery.com/each/

---

Or of course you can simplify it much more like in Viam's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762843/5947043) by finding the row which is the parent of the checkbox instead.

Again, credit to Viam, this can be done by writing

```
$("#allotBtn").click(function(){
    $('#studentListBody tr [type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("tr").hide();
});
```

instead. Demo of this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/jqabpru2/10/

Comment: Another solution is to use `.eq(i)`. This also starts at `0`.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is write the following code instead of your current jQuery code in a click function:

```
var checkList = $("tr[role='row'] .commoncheckbox");
  checkList.each(function(){
    $($(this).closest("tr[role='row']").hide());
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $($(this).closest("tr[role='row']").show());
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a2z0xjn7/17/) is jsfiddle link on this.

[Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php) is how to check a checkbox is checked or not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should do it. No need for loops.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#allotBtn", function() {
      $('#studentListBody input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').closest('tr').hide();
    });
});
```

Also, attaching the click event like this seems super strange - what exactly are you delegating the event to the document itself for anyway? Is the whole thing loaded dynamically?